# Set up tinyproxy to only allow CONNECT to specific host

Tags: proxy, https, tinyproxy

At $DAYJOB, we produce several embedded devices, with access to a management network that often is not connected to the Internet. We also have a management console, running on a stadnard Red Hat or CentOS Linux, which has access to both the management network and the Internet.

I am trying to get the embdded devices to authenticate themselves over the Internet towards a machine that we control over HTTPS, and am evaluating [tinyproxy](https://tinyproxy.github.io/) as a possible solution, but I am at a bit of a loss how to configure it.

In this setup, I want

- to only allow the `CONNECT` method; and
- to only allow the requests to terminate at a specific host (DNS resolvable).

Is it possible to use tinyproxy for this scenario using the standard configuration options? Hacking the sources is of course always an option, but using the standard RPMs is a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible to only allow `CONNECT`, but by using the `Filter` keyword to list the single domain I want to be able to access and using `FilterDefaultDeny Yes`, I can have it restrict forwarding requests to a single host, which is good enough for me.